# Angular: Can you extract status of text responseType?

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

I have a project with server created with spring boot that returns `ResponseEntity` with String to post requests. I would like my angular application to react based on status of response.

```
this.httpClient.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/users',
    {
        "username": username,
        "email": email,
        "password": password
    },
    {
        observe: 'response'
    })
.subscribe(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        alert('Hello!');
    }
 });
```

However with code above I get an error logged to console informing of:

```
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/users"
(status is 200 as expected but alert does not work).
```

I know that I can change third parameter of post to

```
{responseType: 'text'}
```

and get rid of error with it however I don't know to get status code of such response.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can set status of the response object on server.

Comment: As you rightly said `{responseType: 'text'}` will tell Angular not expect a JSON response. And since you are already passing `observe: response` you will get the full http response object (including headers) in the subscription. Using that you can check for the status code.

Comment: @RomanC - status is set on server

Comment: @ashish.gd - unfortunately, as I mentioned - with code that includes observe there is error with message's text visible in post, alert with 'Hello!' doesn't even show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first callback to `subscribe` is known as the `next` callback, which is called whenever the observable emits a value. If there's an error, the `error` callback is called, which can be provided as a second parameter to `subscribe` (there are other alternatives). The reason you're not seeing your `alert` fire when *not* using `responseType: 'text'` is because the callback function you've provided isn't called when there's an error.

As I've already suggested, one option would be to provide an error callback. Here's an example:

```
this.httpClient.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/users',
    { username, email, password },
    { observe: 'response' })
.subscribe(
    response => {
        // Only called for success.
        ...
    },
    errorResponse => {
        // Called when there's an error (e.g. parsing failure).
        if (errorResponse.status === 200) {
            alert('Hello (for real this time)!');
        }
    });
```

---

After re-reading the original question here, I think your real problem might just be that you're not combining `responseType: 'text'` and `observe: 'response'`. Here's what that would look like:

```
this.httpClient.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/users',
    { username, email, password },
    { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' })
.subscribe(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        alert('Hello!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (parseInt(response.status) === 200)
```

Since `response.status` is string and you cannot check with === operator since that check both type and value.